# Custom Query with pagination not working in spring boot JPA repository

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to get all the records based on certain conditions while using Pagination in spring JPA.

I tried two approaches:

1.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM channel c, channel_plans cp, channel_pricing cpr where c.id=cp.channel_id AND cp.id=cpr.plans_id AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between cpr.validity_start and cpr.validity_end and cpr.is_active=1",nativeQuery = true)
Page<channel> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

2. 

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM channel c, channel_plans cp, channel_pricing cpr where c.id=cp.channel_id AND cp.id=cpr.plans_id AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between cpr.validity_start and cpr.validity_end and cpr.is_active=1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM channel c, channel_plans cp, channel_pricing cpr where c.id=cp.channel_id AND cp.id=cpr.plans_id AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between cpr.validity_start and cpr.validity_end and cpr.is_active=1",nativeQuery = true)
Page<channel> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
public class ChannelPricing {
    @Id
    private int id; 
    
    @Column(name="validity_start") 
    private String validityStart; 

    @Column(name="validity_end")
    private String validityEnd; 

    @Column(name="is_active") 
    private int isActive;

    // other entity fields, getters, setters, equals, toString etc...
}
@Entity
    public class Channel {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
        private List<ChannelPlans> plans;
        
        // other entity fields, getters, setters, equals, toString etc...
        }
@Entity
    public class ChannelPlans {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="plans_id",referencedColumnName ="id")
    private List<ChannelPricing> priceInfo;
    // other entity fields, getters, setters, equals, toString etc...
    }
```

I want to get all the records which are active (`is_active=1`). But in both approaches I am receiving active and non-active records.

It seems this query is not executing Could you please help me to understand if i have missed anything?

Comment: You should provide extra information. Can you add `channel` entity in the question? What result did you get? What result do you expect?

Comment: i want to get all the records which are active (is_active=1). But i am receiving records with active and non active

Comment: can you provide `channel` entity class?

Comment: I thin u need channel_pricing to verify{private int id; private double rate; private int views; private int cpt;
    private int tvr;
    private int cpp;
    private String disclaimer;
    private int spots;
    @Column(name="spot_rate")
    private double spotRate;
    @Column(name="spot_length")
    private int spotLength ;
    @Column(name="validity_start")
    private String validityStart;
    @Column(name="validity_end")
    private String validityEnd;
    @Column(name="rate_card")
    private int rateCard;
    @Column(name="is_active")
    private int isActive;}

Comment: To help solve the problem we have to understand your data structure. Please, provide all related entities with necessary fields

Comment: is it because i kept validyStart and validityEnd as String ?

Comment: I have added entities , is it helpful now ?

Comment: Do you want to get all `Сhanel`s where `ChannelPlans` contains active `ChannelPricing`? But if any of them have at least one active price, you will receive **this chanel** as a result of the query. And **the channel** will contain all `ChannelPlans` containing all `ChannelPricing` (active and non-active). You cannot get a part of `ChannelPricing` list inside entity. There are allowed to remain list lazy loaded or fetch full list.

Comment: Yes i want all the channels which contains ChannelPricing satisfies  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between cpr.validity_start and cpr.validity_end and cpr.is_active=1"  condition

Comment: Does the query result contain any channel which includes non-active prices only or query returns channels containing at least one active price?

Comment: As of now , i getting result which contains all the active and non-active price, But i need only active price in a result

Comment: As I stated before: you cannot get a part of `ChannelPricing` list inside another entity. **There are two options:** **1.** Use query returns `dto` class instead of an `entity`  
 **2.** Get list of active `ChannelPricing` as query result

Comment: If it is necessary you can add a `ChannelPlans` field to `ChannelPricing` entity. And add a `Channel` field to `ChannelPlans` entity.

Comment: is it okay if you can show using example ?

Answer (score 0):

If any of `Channel` have at least one active price, your query returns it as a result. The `Channel` instance will contain all `ChannelPlans` containing all `ChannelPricing` (active and non-active). You cannot get a part of `ChannelPricing` list inside another entity. There are allowed to remain list lazy loaded or fetch full list.

To get active `ChannelPricing` only the query should return `Page<ChannelPricing>`

Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Channel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
        
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "channel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChannelPlans> plans;
        
    // other entity fields, getters, setters, equals, toString etc...
}

@Entity
public class ChannelPlans {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
    Channel channel;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "channelPlans", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChannelPricing> priceInfo;
    // other entity fields, getters, setters, equals, toString etc...
}

@Entity
public class ChannelPricing {
    @Id
    private int id; 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "plans_id")
    ChannelPlans channelPlans;
    
    @Column(name="validity_start") 
    private LocalDateTime validityStart; 

    @Column(name="validity_end")
    private LocalDateTime validityEnd; 

    @Column(name="is_active") 
    private int isActive;

    // other entity fields, getters, setters, equals, toString etc...
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ChannelPricingRepository extends JpaReposirory<ChannelPricing, Integer> {
    @Query("from ChannelPricing p where p.isActive=1 and p.validityStart<=now() and p.validityEnd>=now()")
    Page<ChannelPricing> getActivePrices(Pageable pageable);
}
```